# use of articles

Tags: grammaticality

I am always unhappy when it's time for geometry class.

I am always unhappy when it's a time for geometry class.

I am always unhappy when it's the time for geometry class.

which one is correct? If the first one is correct then when do we generally use articles before noun and when we don't?

Comment: This is going to spark off a debate on its v/s it's. Though in this case, I believe the word its should be used.

Comment: There really should be no debate over "it's" versus "its" - they have two different and clearly defined meanings. In this case "it's" should be used. "It's" is a contraction for "it is", which is the correct meaning in this case. "Its" is a possessive pronoun, which indicates something belonging to someone.

Comment: If you are an English learner, as appears to be the case given this type of question, you might be interested in [our sister site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).  It may prove a better fit for questions that are too simple for the current site, since they require nothing more than a native speaker, not an expert.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct, but the issue of: "*When do we generally use articles before noun and when we don't?*" occupies whole chapters of grammar books, so it can't be answered fully here.

Basically, it depends on whether the noun functions as a count noun or uncount noun. Most nouns are either one or the other.

*Computers* can be counted, therefore *computer* is a count noun. *Luck* on the other hand cannot be counted (You cannot say: *I had three lucks yesterday*), so *luck* is an uncount noun.

There is a group of nouns that can be either count or uncount depending on the context. So, for example: *hair* meaning the hair on you head is uncount (*She has nice hair*) but can be counted when referring to individual hairs (*Waiter, there are two hairs in my soup*).

The noun *time* is in this group. It has several meanings, some of which function grammatically as count nouns and others as uncount nouns.

- I have been to Japan two times. [count]
- I don't have time to help you [uncount]
- I hope you have a good time.  [count]
- It's time to go. [uncount]
- You need to move with the times. [count]
- He's doing time for murder. [uncount].

I suggest you use an online dictionary that tells you whether a noun is count or uncount in the context in which you are using it. One such dictionary is:

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/

You can then consult one of the numerous online explanation pages such as the following to determine which article, if any, you need:

http://reske.us/scripts/rules.htm

Comment: This is an over-simplification. At http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/541/03/ is a more accurate treatment:   _The_ is sometimes used with uncountable nouns in the same way it is used with plural countable nouns, that is, to refer to a specific object, [mass,] group, or idea [concept]:

Information is a precious commodity in our computerized world. **but**
The information in your files is correct.
Sugar has become more expensive recently. **but**
Please pass me the sugar. The OP's third alternative is equally acceptable; indeed, his first alternative might be considered an ellipsis.

Comment: @Edwin, Well, as alluded to in the first paragraph, this is an enormously complex area of grammar so any reply will be inevitably be an oversimplification. But in fact I did not even attempt an explanation of why I considered the first sentence the right choice. I just wanted to suggest to the questioner how he or she could go about answering such questions independently. Your comments about the use of the definite article with uncount nouns are of course correct, but I still maintain that the first sentence is the most likely. Would you say: _It's time for lunch_ or _It's the time for lunch_?